# Text overlap in colums; force spacing between columns?

Tags: html, css

When zooming in and out using my browser zoom function, sometimes text creeps upon other elements, an example of which would be when making columns.

**HTML**

```
<div id="columnContainer">
    <div class="column">
        SingleWord <br/>
        Long Word <br/>
        Word
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        Even Longer Word <br/>
        Word <br/>
        Word
    </div>
</div>
```

**.css**

```
#columnContainer{
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6DCb/). Try zooming in (ctrl and +/-) and you'll see "SingleWord" go outside the column and creep into the next one. For better visibility, add `border: 2px solid black;` to `.column`.

How can I make such that the columns are a) stretching to fit contents irrespective of zoom level, and b) when zoomed in far enough, no contents of other column creeps into the other one. I don't want lines to be split (for example, "Long Word" will break off into two words once zoomed in, when this is not what I'd like), and I don't want things to go outside of their defined constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have given a width to the `.column` of `20%`. It takes the width of `20%` as per the width of `parent` element. For the above problem, you can try `word-wrap: break-word;`

```
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the parent div has an arbitrary width: the columns are 20% of that width. I'm not too sure if break-word is what I'm looking for, it splits the word when I'm trying to find a way to prevent this split.

Comment: If you don't want to split the words then you can have option to decrease the font size, using media queries. Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/F6DCb/1/

Answer (score 1):

One CSS feature that is "immune" to zooming is viewport units (vw, vh, vmin, and vmax).  These are supported in modern browsers and for older ones you can get a shim: http://html5polyfill.com/.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8hQP2/.

```
#columnContainer{
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font: normal 2.8vh/1.2 Sans-Serif;
}
```